# Access Denied for user root@localhost on mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, access-denied

My environment is MySql 5.6 on Windows 7 64 bit

I cannot log in as root to the MySql server running on my machine, from the same machine using either the workbench or the mysql command prompt

I followed the steps to change the password here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

if you do that, it leaves an instance of MySQL running in a console window. While that is running, I can connect just fine.

When I Ctrl+C out of that and close the console window, and start MySqlD up as a service, I get access denied again. Despite the password working a minute earlier.

I only have one installation of MySql on the machine, in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

The MySql Windows Service is set to log on as "Network Service" account.

Also, I am using the Password() function to encrypt the password as stated in the steps above

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else finds this I eventually gave up and reinstalled mysql and made a note of the root password this time. What a palaver!